# Not able to connect to PPTP server in Debian in a lab

Tags: networking, debian, windows-server-2012-r2

Currently I am making on a lab to test out vpn connection.. the topology is something like this

There is a picture of it down there with IPs please take a look ..
Why am I not able to connect ? I tried many things regarding modem hangup error. First  problem I got is LCP timeout but I have already fixed it using workarounds on the internet.Now this is my current problem.I have setup NAT on the asav firewall. What is wrong ? Should I emulate internet connection on the windows server first using this https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/canberrapfe/2012/10/09/fake-internet-connectivity-for-your-lab-tricking-ncsi/ or its not even related? Do suggest other vpn solution other than PPTPD that is able to use windows built in vpn client and works in a lab if needed. Thanks in advance

Images:

[The network setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMQDf.png)

[GRE TCPDUMP packet captured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FY9lb.png)

[Port 1723 is open perfectly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w39al.png)

[Error when connecting to vpn on windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpauS.png)

[Log of pptpd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srNhP.png)

Comment: I have also allowed everything in ASA access-list just because this is just a lab to test the vpn connection

Comment: A PPTP tunnel consists of a TCP connection **and** a GRE tunnel. The first one obviously succeeds, but the second probably gets blocked by the firewall. Check with `tcpdump -nvvi net_interface_name ip proto gre` on the Debian box, if some GRE packets arrive.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I solved one of the problems.. at first I have no packet coming from GRE protocol.. but then I allowed it in my ASA then the packet comes in.. but I am still unable to connect to the vpn

Comment: You should check the logs again (`journalctl -u pptpd -e`) and update the logs in your question. Also it is better to include text in the question instead of external images. Selecting text and using `CTRL + K` displays it as code (or you can indent 4 spaces).

Comment: Thanks for  your suggestion but I cant seem to find a way to copy the terminal output from bare linux without installing a desktop environment.I will update the log picture and gre packet being captured.It is still stuck at modem hangup btw

Comment: `tcpdump` sees traffic before the firewall on the Debian machine gets a shot at it. Check your `INPUT` firewall chain (`iptables -nvL INPUT`) and allow GRE traffic if it is blocked (`iptables -I INPUT -p gre -j ACCEPT`)

Comment: I have checked its empty.. I have also tried allowing it using your iptables  ACCEPT command.. still no luck

Comment: Found a workaround.. I set up L2TP and it works